# Apollo server caching with Redis and SQL as a datasource

Tags: graphql, apollo-client, apollo-server

So I'm schema stitching with apollo-server-express which I believe makes use of graphql-tools and as per docs here: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/caching#adding-cache-hints-statically-in-your-schema

"Important note on compatibility: Setting cache hints is currently incompatible with the graphql-tools implementation of schema stitching, because cache hints are not appropriately communicated from one service to the other."

Similar thread: [Apollo Server - Confusion about cache/datasource options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53358443/apollo-server-confusion-about-cache-datasource-options/56267161#56267161)

I currently have my code caching the response from the database in the same way the question proposes, but I could not fully understand the accepted answer and was unsure if said accepted answer was leaning towards client-side caching for that case.

So I'm at a loss as to how I could implement caching on Apollo. What other options are there?

Comment: Do you have ownership over the different services you're stitching together, or are you stitching together remote schemas that you don't have any control over? If it's the former, are these services also built on top of Apollo?

Comment: Yes I do and yes, they are built on top of Apollo.